# Typescript: type infer in function arguments

Tags: typescript, type-inference

try to infer type Data by input params, but it infer 'unknown' when data is function type.
[image]

```js
declare function getTypeOf<Data>(options: { data: Data }): any;

getTypeOf({
  data() {
    return {
      name: "123",
      age: 1,
    };
  },
  getData() {
    return {
      name: 123,
    };
  },
});
```

when change data to a obj, it works; or just add  getData in the type params, it also works. but why? any doc?
[image]

i need some doc or explains

Comment: How do you expect the compiler to infer the `getData` if it isn't mentioned in the `getTypeOf`?

Comment: i want it to infer data, not getData. the first image show type tips on "data".

Comment: ① Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)... especially the important fact that `getData` has an error, and what that error is.

Comment: ② The problem is that excess property checking causes an error inside your object literal, and then the rest of the type isn't available for inference.  Generally speaking, you should fix your errors so they don't interfere. One way to do that is [shown here](https://tsplay.dev/Nd8kdN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

To get the argument type you need

```
function getArgumentType<T>(t: T): T { return t; }
```

In your case you need if to have `data` prop

```
function getArgumentDotDataType<T extends {data: unknown}>(t: T): T['data'] { return t.data; }
```